# OpenSearch: use vector search in combination with should

Tags: opensearch, vector-database, semantic-search

Suppose my index has:

- A vector field called **"text_encoded"**
- A field called **"field1"**, that can contain one or more of the following classes: **"A", "B", "C"**
  as list (ex. **"field1" : ["A"]**, or **"field1" : ["A", "C"]**)

I would like to write an OpenSearch query that can:

- select the samples with **field1** classes containing either **"A" OR "C"**
- return **similarity scores only**

If I use the "should" instruction, it returns **relevance scores** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query enables you to achieve this. Note that it uses [Exact kNN with Scoring Script](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/knn-score-script/), as opposed to approximate kNN.

First, the `script_score.query` clause fetches a subset of documents where `field1` is either "A" or "B". Then, the `script_score.script` clause performs kNN on the aforementioned set.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            { "match": { "field1": "A" }},
            { "match": { "field1": "B" }}
          ]
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "knn_score",
        "lang": "knn",
        "params": {
          "field": "text_encoded",
          "query_value": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
          "space_type": "cosinesimil"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!